# How to control the dimensions of \colorbox

Tags: colorbox

I want a long narrow horizontal colored rectangle, something more like a thick line, but I cannot get the height below a certain amount. The best I can come up with is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
xxxxx\colorbox{red}{%
\phantom{------------------}
}%
xxxxx 
\end{document}
```

where the number of `-` controls the length but I would like *at most half* the height of:

[image]

I have tried various solutions proposed for questions about height of boxes but was not able to find anything that did it. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @Roboticist  That question talks about _increasing_ the height/depth.  Here a decrease is requested.

Comment: @AndrewSwann -- i;ve voted to reopen, and i have a working answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `-` is sits an box with white space around it.  You can see this by writing

```
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\fbox{-}
```

which produces

[image: Sample dash]

indicating the box containing the dash sits on the baseline and rises to the height of a capital letter.  (Actually `---` is producing a different glyph, but the same considerations apply.)  To get better control use a `\rule`.  The syntax is

```
\rule[2pt]{3cm}{1.5ex}
```

to produce a rule of width `3cm`, height `1.5ex` all raised `2pt` above the baseline.  In your case to fit with the `x`'s `\rule{2cm}{1ex}` should suffice, since `1ex` is the nominal height of `x` in the font, but there are some optical effects from the serifs, so I suggest

```
\rule[-0.05ex]{2cm}{1.1ex}
```

As this is the actual shape you want to see you can enclose it in a simple `\textcolor` rather than having to make a phantom.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

xxxxx\textcolor{red}{\rule[-0.05ex]{2cm}{1.1ex}}xxxxx

\end{document}
```

Comment: the answer i had used `\raisebox{.5ex}{\colorbox{red}{\hphantom ...}` but your solution is better.  the problem with the `\hphantom`, even with a rule, is that depth is added.  (the only reason for this comment is to report the depth effect.)

Comment: @Roboticist As John Holt once put it in "How Children Fail", one ought to strive for being `question oriented` as opposed to `answer oriented`. Please think of the resulting chilling effect which is very real.

Comment: @Andrew Swann and barbara beeton I know, I know but I cannot help thanking you for averting my being chilled.